# Second annihilator of subspace is the subspace itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{C}$ with dual space $X'$ and let $M,N$ be subspaces of $X',X$ respectively. Define the annihilator subspaces of $M$ and $N$ as

$$
M_\circ = \{x \in X: f(x) = 0 \  \forall f \in M\} \quad \text{and} \quad N^\circ = \{f \in X': f(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in N  \}$$

How can we show that if $M \subset X' $ is finite-dimensional, then $(M_{\circ})^\circ = M$?

I am trying to do this by induction on the dimension of $M$, and managed to show that the base case holds by proving that if $f$ is a non-zero element of $X'$, then $ (\{f\}_\circ)^\circ = \operatorname{span} f$. For the inductive step, I showed that $M \subset (M_{\circ})^\circ$ as follows: if we let $M$ have a basis of $m+1$  vectors $f_1,\dots,f_{m+1}$, then $M$ decomposes as the direct sum $M_1 \oplus M_2$ where $M_1$ is spanned by the first $m$ basis vectors and $M_2$ is spanned by $f_{m+1}$; by the induction hypothesis, $(M_{1, \circ})^\circ = M_1$ and $ (M_{2, \circ})^\circ = M_2$. Since the assignment of annihilators reverses inclusions, $ M_1 = (M_{1, \circ})^\circ \subset (M_{ \circ})^\circ$ and $M_2 =(M_{2, \circ})^\circ \subset (M_{ \circ})^\circ$, so that $M = M_1 \oplus M_2 \subset (M_{\circ})^\circ$ also.

However, I am having trouble proving the inclusion $(M_{\circ})^\circ \subset M$. How could we use the induction hypothesis in this case? I was thinking of looking for a basis of $(M_{\circ})^\circ$, but I haven't yet shown that $(M_{\circ})^\circ$ is finite-dimensional, so I'm not sure how to begin doing that.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Theorem 1.** Every finite dimensional subspace of topological vector space is closed.

**Proof.** See theorem 1.21 in Rudin's Functional Analysis.

> **Theorem 2.** If $X$ is a locally convex space and $M$ its linear subspace, then $(M_o)^o=\operatorname{cl}_{w^*}(M)$.

**Proof.** See theorem 4.7 in Rudin's Functional Analysis.

> **Theorem 3.** If $X$ is a locally convex space and $M$ its finite dimensional linear subspace, then $(M_o)^o=M$.

**Proof.** Follows from previous two theorems.

Comment: This is helpful, but I have not covered local convexity and weak-star topologies yet, so I don't think I am allowed to use those concepts in my work.